# Search column for value, if found paste row transposed to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, lookup, paste

I'm trying to create a VBA macro that will:

1. search a column for a specific value (that the user types into a cell/dialogue box)
2. If found, paste the row (starting from a specific column) transposed into another sheet.

**My problem/question is;** there can be multiple instances of my lookup value, I need to find the first instance and paste as described above, then continue to cycle through and paste the row of the 2nd instance of the lookup value adjacent to the 1st paste and so on for all instances of the value.

This seems like it should be an easy FOR loop, but I am having difficulty

Answer (score 0):

If you have a workbook with 2 sheets: sheet1,sheet2 and cell/dialogue box in Range B1 you can try the below Sub

**Code**

```
Option Explicit


Public Sub find_move()

Dim i As Integer

Dim i1 As Integer

Dim start As Integer

Dim count_ As Long

Dim col As Range

Set col = Sheet1.Range("A1")

start = 1

count_ = Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

For i = start To count_

If Sheet1.Cells(i, 1) = Sheet1.Range("B1") Then

i1 = i


 Sheet1.Activate

 Sheet1.Range(Cells(i1, 1), Cells(count_, 1)).Select

 Selection.Copy

 Sheet2.Activate

 Sheet2.Paste




start = i

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate

End If



Next



End Sub
```